# Can I use Objective-C To Open Other Apps On My Mac?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, scripting

I want to write a script that will open Xcode, build a project, test a project, and that's about it. I know that I can use Automator or ScriptEditor to do this. I also know I could write a simple Python script to do this (very preferred) but I don't know my way around Python well enough yet. I know my way around Objective-C though, although I don't know if it can be used as a scripting language. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this using Objective-C, (if it even can be), or know how to track down some sample Python code that I could modify to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way for Objective-c App is to do using `raft tool` with `python script`. So install the raft from [here](http://raft.apple.com) and then inside the preference give the installation path below.

`/AppleInternal/Library/Frameworks/Raft.framework/bin/raft`

After, follow the below steps:-

1) Create new test script.

2) Use below method for launching and run the Xcode.

```
def runTest(params):
# Your testing code here
target.dock().dockItems()["Xcode"].click()
target.processes()["Xcode"].mainWindow().toolbar().buttons()["Run"].click()
logPass() # This line is implicit and can be removed
```

3) In the similar ways you can write your own function using python script to automate testing for your App.

Comment: If you want to run multiple function, you can call inside this runTest method.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a console Objective-C app which will perform your steps. But as any C code it should be compiled.
For python you can check [this manual](http://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/building-and-running-python-scripts-with-xcode-6-1/), but I guess a Xcode buildscript will be a solution for you.